# Increase row limit during export in excel xml format using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I can export 8,000 rows. But i can't export 10,000 rows.

Previous i tried using .xlsx format but in .xlsx data field and number field is change their format. PHP Sample Code is in below

```
 $title = "SampleStockReport";
 $xls = new ExcelXml($title);
 $xls->home();

 $xls->newRow();
 foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
     if(isset($tableHeadKeyTranslator[$key])) $key = 
                  $tableHeadKeyTranslator[$key];
     $column = ($key);
     $xls->labelHeader($column);

 }
 $xls->endRow();


 foreach ($data as $indx => $thisLine) {
      $xls->newRow();
      foreach ($thisLine as $key => $value) {

           $column = ($value);
           $xls->label($column);

      }

      $xls->endRow();
 }

 $xls->send();
```

When i export all data then this page is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved my problem. Increase PHP memory limit in php.ini file

memory_limit = 128M to memory_limit = 512M